# Java Generics at method level

Tags: java, generics

Can anyone please explain me below code

```
 public <T extends Emp> void foo(ArrayList<T> list) {
    list.add(list.remove(0)); // (cycle front element to the back)
}
```

I am trying to understand how Generics will apply on void return type.
Note: i have changed the code now it is not giving any error.

Comment: It does not apply to the void. It's for the ArrayList.

Comment: This code will not compile. You're trying to add a `String` to an `ArrayList<T>` where `T` is definitely not a string.

Comment: They won't apply to void.

Comment: i have modified the code.. i was trying to understand generics at void return type.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh its not giving any error. its compile fine..

Comment: Yes. It *is* fine. What do you mean when you ask "how do they apply to void"? Please see my answer if it helps

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Thanks for your example and explanation. its really helps me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to understand how generics will apply on void return type.

This is only a syntax. Generics do not apply to `void` return type, they apply to the method as a whole.

The name and restrictions on the generic parameter need to go somewhere in the text of your program. In a class declaration they follow the class name in angular brackets. In a generic method declaration they follow the accessibility designator `public`, and precedes the return type `void`.

One could easily imagine an alternative placement of generic types, such as

```
public void foo<T extends Emp>(ArrayList<T> list)  // Imaginary syntax
```

or even

```
public void foo(ArrayList<T> list) <T extends Emp> // Imaginary syntax
```

but Java designers decided on the placement before the return type designator.

Answer (score 2):

Generics won't be applied to `void`.

If you say that the type is `<T extends Emp>`, you are saying, that any subtype of Emp can be applied in place of `T`.

In your code, You can use `<T>` instead of `<T extends Emp>` as you aren't doing anything with `Emp`

```
public <T> void foo(ArrayList<T> list) {
    list.add(list.remove(0)); // (cycle front element to the back)
}
```

Regarding how it'll work, the type will be provided by you when you use this method and at compile time, java will place required casts automatically. So, if you are using this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
// Add some items into list
foo(list);
```

in that case, your `foo()` method will find out that type `<T>` is `String` and so, will behave something like:

```
public void foo(ArrayList<String> list) {
    list.add((String)(list.remove(0)));
}
```